# How to plot a wav file while it is playing

Tags: matlab, plot, wav

How do you go about plotting a wave file on matlab while the wavfile is playing. I would like to plot amplitude vs time. I have tried to attempt this with my following code below:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('test.wav');
sound(y,Fs);
clear y Fs
```

Comment: Your attempt isn't plotting anything. It's just reading in a file, playing it, and clearing up whatever memory was needed to read in the sound.  Am I understanding you correctly that you want the amplitude of the wav file to be plotted as the sound is playing?  That's going to be very hard especially because there's no way for you to synchronize where the sound is currently being played with where you're supposed to update and plot the figure.  This can't be done IMHO.

Comment: @rayryeng, is there a way to implement this with a bit of delay, so although its not fully synchronized whats the closest way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sound` you don't have a real chance to do this, but using the `audioplayer` class you can do this:

```
function syncPlayerDemo()
%some example music
load handel;
%set up audio player
player = audioplayer(y, Fs);
[samples,channels]=size(y);
%calculate timeline
t=linspace(0,1/Fs*(samples-1),samples);
%initialize full plot, update will only move the visible area using xlim
h=plot(t,y);
%set up callback to update every <TimerPeriod> s
player.TimerFcn=@timerFcn;
player.TimerPeriod=0.1;
player.playblocking()
end

function timerFcn(source,data)
%an area of length <area> s will be visible
area=1;
position=(source.CurrentSample-1)/source.SampleRate;
%move visible area, current position is in the center
set(gca,'XLim',[position-area/2,position+area/2]);
%used a waitbar for testing, might be commented in
%waitbar(source.CurrentSample/source.TotalSamples);
end
```

The quality of this plot might be further increased using a plot which automatically moves to the side, using the `timerFcn` only to resynchronize.

Comment: Implementing the code you have given me, I eventually got a plot. but it does not seem to be updating as the track is playing.

Comment: What version of matlab do you use?

Comment: The version of matlab I use is R2013B

Comment: Okay, then I have no Idea why it is not working on your PC.

Comment: I'll try to look into it later, thanks for your help!

Comment: My last question is how would I implement loading a wav file into the function you gave me? I know I cannot utilize `load handel` So I have tried replacing it with  `[y,Fs] = audioread('test.wav');` but I am not getting a figure as smooth as is I had `load handel`.

Comment: Did you made any changes to the code to get it working? How long is your audio file, and what is fs? It might be to mouch data for the simple approach that I used.

Comment: I figured out how to get it to work thanks. Is there anyway I can get this into bars. for example like a spectrogram music bar that changes depending on the wave form, similar to like so [link](http://www.wallpapersis.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/music-DJ-audio-spectrum-4.jpg)?

Comment: Using `spectogram` you get the required raw data, then you have to plot it using `bar` or similar, and finally a callback similar to the one in my answer to update. .